# Available API levels in Android Virtual Device manager

Tags: android-emulator

I'm running ADT/Eclipse 21.1.0 and I want to emulate my application's behavior with different API versions. I installed a bunch of different API versions through Android SDK manager. I set the min SDK version to 11, and I'm changing the target SDK in project properties (Project Build Target). All this seems to be working fine. However, when I go to Android Virtual Device manager and try to create different devices I can only change the Device field, and the only available Target option is "Android 4.2 - API level 17".

Is there a way to create a device that runs a different Android version?

Thanks,

Veljko

Answer (score 0):

You may have resolved this issue by now but if you hadn't restarted the Android Virtual Device Manager that could have been why it didn't see the newly installed SDKs.